# How many possible ways of distributing 20 red balls and 20 blue balls among 4 students?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am dividing 20 red balls and 20 blue balls among 4 students in a way that no student gets less than 3 or more than 7 of each ball?  How can I carry out the distribution.

All I know, if there were no conditions, the solution would have been straight as follows:
$$\left(
                \begin{array}{c}
                  20+4-1 \\
                  4-1 \\
                \end{array}
              \right)
$$
for red balls and
$$
\left(
                \begin{array}{c}
                 20+4-1 \\
                  4-1 \\
                \end{array}
              \right)
$$
for blue balls.  And thus, the solution would be
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c}
                  20+4-1 \\
                  4-1 \\
                \end{array}
              \right)
\times
\left(
                \begin{array}{c}
                  20+4-1 \\
                  4-1 \\
                \end{array}
              \right).
$$
Now, how should I involve the given conditions?

I was thinking of formulating an exponential generating function.  But I am stuck!  Is there a simple way of looking at this problem?

Comment: If no student gets less than $3$ of each ball, then we would require at least $4 \cdot 3 = 12$ balls of each color.  Please clarify.

Comment: What? If no student gets less than 3 balls of each type, then each student must get 3 red balls and 3 blue balls. But there are four students, so that's 12 red balls and 12 blue balls already. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you mean that no student gets less than 3 or more than 7 balls *in total* (as opposed to "of each color")?

Comment: I am sorry, there was an oversight in the formulation of the question.  But I have revisited it and made suitable changes.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider just one of the colours of balls.

The number of ways to distribute 20 indistinguishable objects between 4 people is equal to the number of solutions to

$$ w + x + y + z = 20$$

for integers $w,x,y,z$ with $3 \leqslant w,x,y,z \leqslant 7$. This is the same as solving

$$ w + x + y + z = 8$$

for integers $w,x,y,z$ with $0 \leqslant w,x,y,z \leqslant 4$. You know how many solutions this has when the only restriction is that $w,x,y,z \geqslant 0$. Now if we want to find how many cases there are with, say, $w > 4$ then we can set $w' = w-5 \geqslant 0$ and solve

$$ w' + x + y + z = 3.$$

where $w',x,y,z \geqslant 0$. You know how many solutions this has, now repeat this for $x,y,z$. Finally, notice that we can't simultaneously have any two variables greater than 4, so it's easy to apply inclusion-exclusion from here.